# DirectX Install Directory

Tags: directx

So, I tried installing Microsoft DirectX 2010, when I was setting the directory of in the installer I put it to the wrong directory that I wanted it in. Now, every time I open the installer, it doesn't give me an option to change the directory, it just says continue and install. If anyone has a solution to this that would be really nice.

EDIT: Also forgot to note that when I installed it on my D: drive (its supposed to be on C: ) I get the error code S1023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S1023 issue is detailed in [this post](https://walbourn.github.io/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error/). Because the setup just outright failed, and it's built on ancient pre-MSI technology, you need to clean out the old installation manually.

- Delete the failed install directory
- Using `regedit` to delete `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\DirectX SDK`, `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DirectX SDK`. If you are on a x64 system (which I hope you are), also delete `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX SDK`.
- Edit your system environment variables and remove the entry for `DXSDK_DIR`.

**The DirectX SDK is deprecated.** If you are using VS 2012 or later -or- the Windows 8.0 SDK or later, and you are using DirectX 11 or DirectX 12, then you don't need it. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

> There are a few cases where it's still legitimate to use the legacy DirectX SDK as covered in [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://walbourn.github.io/the-zombie-directx-sdk/), but for the most part you should avoid using it for new projects.

If you are trying to get an old game to work, try installing the latest [DXSETUP](https://walbourn.github.io/dxsetup-update/)/[DXWSETUP](https://walbourn.github.io/dxwebsetup-update/) but keep in mind that it doesn't actually install DirectX at all. See [Not So Direct Setup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/)

**UPDATE**: There are now really no reasons to use the legacy DirectX SDK at all. See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2021 Edition)?](https://aka.ms/dxsdk) for the overall status and details.

- For legacy D3DX9/D3DX10/D3DX11, use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package per [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/). No need for the legacy DirectX SDK or to use legacy DXSETUP for this solution.
- For XAudio2 on Windows 7, use the [Microsoft.XAudio2.Redist](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XAudio2.Redist/) NuGet package per [Microsoft Docs](https://aka.ms/XAudio2Redist).